# store shortened-url in DB?

Tags: url, google-api

I'd like to shorten URLs for sharing purposes. (probably will use google's)

Is it a good idea to store the shortened-url in database and use it next (assuming a content has a fixed url)

Do people call api (eg. to get the shortened-url from google) every time they need a shortened-url?
(maybe google expire the urls?)

Or store them in cache for the amount of time (while the shortened-url works)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store urls in db as they are string based values. But Google is already doing it for you.
You would normally store id,Original-Url,Condensed-Url.Go ahead,fill up your db with junk.Google has a bad name for removing its services ;).

Comment: ah, I should have mentioned that I'd like to get the shortened-url everytime a user click a `share` button for a post. (think of the share button in Stackoverflow). So I was worried about network latency